# How can convert script coding into angularJS coding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

this is my  script coding for left side menu slide left and right. I want to convert it into angularJS, I copied it from other website and unable to understand.

```
<script>
    var menuLeft = document.getElementById('cbp-spmenu-s1'), 
        showLeftPush = document.getElementById('showLeftPush'),
        body = document.body;

    showLeftPush.onclick = function() {
        classie.toggle(this, 'active');
        classie.toggle(body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright');
        classie.toggle(menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open');
        disableOther('showLeftPush');
    };

    function disableOther(button) {
        if (button !== 'showLeftPush') {
            classie.toggle(showLeftPush, 'disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that this code is some sort of toggle functionality. So let me try to explain how we can convert this!

The code starts at the `onclick`, so in angular that will be `ng-click`, also in angular you can write this in the HTML like so

```
<button id="showLeftPush" ng-click="test=!test;" ng-init="test=false;" ng-class="{'active': test, 'disabled': test}"></button>
```

In the above line, I will initialize test variable to false. then `ng-click` will toggle this variable. Then you are toggling the active class for the button. So the angular equivalent for that will be `ng-class` where the test will be a boolean, if `test` is true, then the class will be added. I do the same thing for disabled class also.

Similarly I add the other classes to the other element like.

**Body HTML:**

```
<body ng-class="{'cbp-spmenu-push-toright': test}" ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
```

**Div with ID - cbp-spmenu-s1:**

```
<div id="cbp-spmenu-s1" ng-class="{'cbp-spmenu-open': test}">left</div>
```

Please use this as a starting point and continue building you angular App.

I have included a demo for your reference.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>